# PHP Excel Bar Chart For Time

Tags: php, excel, time, bar-chart, phpexcel

I need PHP Excel Bar Chart for time series as Y-Axis. But I cannot able to format it into time or even with string which can accept colon(it may seems as time).

$dataSeriesValues = array(
new PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues('String', 'Trends!$B$2:$B$'.count($classification_chart_data), null, 12),
);

The above code is where I am trying to change the time format for Y-axis.
[image: PHP Excel Chart What I Have]
[image: PHP Excel Chart What I Needed]

`

```
$dataSeriesValues = array(
            new PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues('String', 'Trends!$B$2:$B$'.count($classification_chart_data), null, 12),
        );
```

`
The above is the actual code.

$dataSeriesValues = array(
new PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues('String', 'Trends!$B$2:$B$'.count($classification_chart_data), YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS, 12),
);

$dataSeriesValues = array(
new PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues('String', 'Trends!$B$2:$B$'.count($classification_chart_data), FORMAT_TEXT, 12),
);

Like this I have tried....

Comment: [How do I format my posts?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$worksheet->getStyle('B2:D2')->getNumberFormat()->setFormatCode(\PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\NumberFormat::FORMAT_DATE_TIME4);

$dataSeriesLabels1 = [
new DataSeriesValues(DataSeriesValues::DATASERIES_TYPE_NUMBER, 'Worksheet!$C$2', 'h:mm:ss', 1), // 2011
];

$dataSeriesValues1 = [new DataSeriesValues(DataSeriesValues::DATASERIES_TYPE_NUMBER, 'Worksheet!$C$2:$C$5', 'h:mm:ss', 1),];

[Sample Image for PHP SpreadSheet with time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wbxkw.png)

In this way we can use Time format in PhpSpreadSheet